# What does "Not authorized to send emails" mean in the context of Resend?

Tags: node.js, email

My company uses Resend and I have a Resend API key issued by my company.

I'm trying to send a test email to my company email account from the same account.

my Node.js code:

```
import { Resend } from 'resend'
const resend = new Resend("api-key")

const sendTestEmail = async () => {
    try {
        await resend.emails.send({
            from: 'Test <my.email@companydomain>',
            to: ['my.email@companydomain'],
            subject: 'Test',
            text: 'Hello World!'
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

sendTestEmail()
```

When I run the code above, I get the following exception:

```
{
  name: 'validation_error',
  message: 'Not authorized to send emails from <companydomain>',
  statusCode: 401
}
```

It's unclear what thing is "not authorized". As far as I'm aware, it could be any of the following:

- My API key is not authorized.
- The machine that I'm working on is not authorized.
- The JS API is not authorized.
- The company Resend account is not authorized.

If anyone is familiar with Resend, I would deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: The field text is working as expected? I'm facing some trouble to get the text to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Resend API documentation](https://resend.com/docs/api-reference/introduction), the 401 code means:

> `401` The API key used was missing.

I hope that the second line of your code is a redacted api key, otherwise replace the `api-key` by your valid api key should solve.

Comment: Turns out that the API key was registered to a domain other than the one used by my company email. So the API key didn't exist on the domain that I was trying to send emails from.